# "Ghosting" background color of fixed div when scrolling in Chrome

Tags: css

I'm using grid 960_12 for my grid layout.

I have a fixed nav bar with a div in it with a red background.

When scrolled in Chrome, there is a "ghosting" effect. This is not present in Safari.

Any ideas? The ghosting happens on all pages, not just on top of photos that scroll underneath the red bar.

If you need me to post my css, I'd be happy.

Here's a screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Can you post the shortest possible code to reproduce your issue? You can use [JSBin](http://www.jsbin.com) or [JSFiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net) to host a live example showing the issue.

Comment: this is called artifacts, not ghosts

Comment: ahh, thank you for the clarification. I'm new to this stuff, so didn't know what to call it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding `-webkit-backface-visibility:hidden;` to the div that was ghosting should fix the issue.